# preg_match Unknown modifier for getting data

Tags: php, html, preg-match, delimiter

I have a website, that needs to read information from another website. And show it.

Currently i'm using a different website as example. However it does not work yet.

The code i have:

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}

$html=getHTML("https://www.sparkfun.com/",10);
preg_match("/<title>(.*)</title>/i", $html, $match);
$title = $match[1];
```

If it is right, it should give me the title of the page.

However i get this error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't'
```

I get the error at this line:

```
preg_match("/<title>(.*)</title>/i", $html, $match);
```

Now i have read something about delimiters. However i just can't figure it out yet :/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try `preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $html, $match);`

Comment: With this i get the same error as i get with arkascha. Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: check weather you getting html or not from curl call?

Answer (score 1):

You are using your regex delimited (/) inside the pattern, which certainly is not allowed. So either use another delimiter (| maybe) or escape that forward slash inside the

```
preg_match("|<title>(.*)</title>|i", $html, $match)
```

With your attempt the regex engine expects the pattern itself to be finished after the second slash (the one inside `</title`) and treats everything after that as modifiers. The first character following the slash is a `t`, thus it complains about an undefined modifier `t`.

"Delimiters" are used in "perl compatible regular expressions" (`pcre_...()` functions) to mark the start end end of the actual expression pattern. That makes compiling the pattern *much* more effective (saving time). However it has the side effect that whatever character you use as delimiters (typically the `/`, but you can actually chose *any* character) cannot directly be used inside the pattern itself any more. For obvious reasons, once you think about it.

This is all documented: http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Okay, i'm starting to get it now. Thank you for the explanation! :) I also changed the code to what you said. However right now i'm getting the error: "Notice: Undefined offset: 1". I have read that this is because it is empty. However how can it be empty??

Comment: That means that your pattern does not match. Try dumping `$match`, you will see that it does not contain a match.

Comment: when i var_dump $match i get: "array(0) { }"    Does this mean it does not find anything with <title></title> ???

Comment: Yes, exactly. Most likely no page title is set in `$html`?

Comment: You really want to read the documentations of the functions you use. Your questions are answered in there: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Sorry for late respone. I will take a look there :) Thank you.

Comment: Alright @arkascha. Right now i can show the whole content with this code: http://pastebin.com/816iPe5u . However the whole site is in a <pre> element. How can i style this so it is readable?

Comment: I am confused: that is not the content you posted, but your `cURL` code. Of interest would be what is actually contained in your `$data` variable. If that holds a valid html markup structure, then question is if that contains a `<title>` element in the header.

Comment: the site where i need to get content out is all a <pre>. It says witch rooms are availible, and where and when we have meetings today. However, this is all in a <pre> and i don't know how to style it properly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what a `<pre>` element and "styling" has to do with the question you asked. You asked about some issue with matching some `<title>` element in (most likely) some html markup.